# Java Triangle Pattern Printing

Tags: java

Trying to write a program that will print a number of triangle patterns, both hollow and solid. I have implemented this by using constructors, along with other utility methods. As of right now I am trying to display a triangle of size 7 with the following character (*).

for some reason I am only getting the following output: 0000. I have created a test triangle down below

```
Triangle s1 = new Triangle(7, '*');
s1.displaySolidUL();

public class Triangle {

// Declare & intialize data fields
final private static char defaultChar = '*';
final private static int defaultSize = 10;

private static char triangleChar;
private static int triangleSize;

private static int triangleCount = 0;


// Constructors 
 public Triangle() {
  this(defaultSize, defaultChar);
 }

 public Triangle(int s) {
  this(s, defaultChar);
 }

 public Triangle(char n) {
  this(n, defaultChar);
 }

 public Triangle(int size, char character) {
  if ((triangleSize <= 0) || (triangleSize > 50)) {
     size = defaultSize;
     // System.out.println(errorSizeMsg);
  } else if (triangleChar == ' ') {
     character = defaultChar;
     // System.out.println(errorBlankChar);
  } else {
     size = triangleSize;
     character = triangleChar;

     // increment triangle count
     triangleCount++;
  }
}

// Accessors and Mutators
public int getSize() {
  return triangleSize;
}

public char getChar() {
  return triangleChar;
}

public void setSize(int size) {
  triangleSize = size;
}

public void setChar(char character) {
  triangleChar = character;
}


// Main methods for displaying triangles
public void displaySolidLL() {

}

public void displaySolidLR() {

}

public void displaySolidUL() {
  for (int row = 0; row <= triangleSize; row++) {
     for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
        System.out.print(triangleChar);
     }
    System.out.println();
  }

}  

public void displaySolidUR() {

}


// Other utility classes
// Printing out new lines
public static void newLine(int numLines) {
  for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
     System.out.println();
  }
}

// Display triangle count
public static void getTriangleCount() {
  System.out.print("The total number of triangles printed equals: " + triangleCount);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this problem seems to be testing for loop design.

Consider these nested for loops:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        System.out.print('0'); // will iterate i number of times
    }

    System.out.println(); // creates a new line
}
```

The above commented code will print a triangle with a base of ten. You could expand upon this for loop design to make an equilateral triangle / inverted triangle.

I hope this helps you conceptualize the approach and expand it for your needs.

Comment: Revised my loop to your revised design .. still does not seem to cooperate